# Sentence construction 活躍をしてる現場

Tags: syntax, relative-clauses

> 他のヒーローが俺くらい**活躍をしてる現場**なんて見たことがない

In this sentence, the main noun in the clause before なんて is 現場, so I would understand this sentence as "I haven't seen a place that the other heroes flourish as much as me". I understand the meaning conveyed, but I would have expected a structure like:

> 他のヒーローが**現場で**俺くらい活躍をしてるなんて見たことがない

Is my structure wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, relatives clauses are placed before the noun they modify unlike in English.  「他のヒーローが俺くらい活躍をしてる」 modifies 「現場」to convey the meaning *A place **where** other heroes are doing as well as I am*. As for your second sentence, I think it conveys another meaning because で marks the location of the action. Therefore, 「他のヒーローが現場で俺くらい活躍をしてる」means *Other heroes are doing as well as me **in the field***. Finally, by adding 「なんて見たことがない」, it changes the meaning to *I've never seen **a scene where** other heroes are doing as well as I am* and *I've never seen another hero do as much **in the field** as I do*, respectively.

Comment: I think what threw me off at first was the lack of preposition to say "where/at/in", but I just remembered that it's actually a very common usage.

Comment: @Simon - The second sentence would also sound more natural if you inserted some noun or nominalizer between してる and なんて, such as とこ(ろ) and の.

Answer (score 4):

I think your understanding is (somewhat) wrong at the first place. I would say:

- *I've never seen a field/crime scene where another hero is as successful as I am.*

"他のヒーローが俺くらい活躍をしてる" modifies "現場" to convey the meaning "A place where other heroes are doing as well as I am..."

I don't know the context so I don't know if there's a (or, many) heroes that came to field/crime scene but struggles to success, but if that's so then yes it can be "他のヒーローが現場で俺くらい活躍をしてるなんて見たことがない". Which indicates that other hero hasn't done much in the field/crime scene.

Though, it changes translation a little bit:

- *I've never seen another hero do as much in the field/crime scene as I do.*

Still, the meaning is same.